# Is it possible to pull a powerpoint from a sharepoint website and serve it up to a client with Asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

For my company, my project is to create a help button on the client side, which is done in Vue, that downloads a powerpoint guide for the user on how to use the app. Because the user needs authentication to log into the app, I thought it would make sense if I could have the server which is a ASP.net core web api talk to the company sharepoint and pull the powerpoint and then serve it up either statically or dynamically to the client. The problem is, I have searched quite a lot over the internet and haven't been able to find out if this is possible. I have seen other people make apps talking to a sharepoint and pulling simple data such as list of numbers and such. It also seems like there is a good package which is the Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client and Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime packages which seem to have maybe the functionality I am looking for. My question is, is this a viable solution? If so, can anyone point me to some help, or maybe some good documentation to look at.

Comment: How often is this guide updated? Why do you want to pull it from SharePoint at run time? If your web API runs in a public web server or DMZ or somewhere in the cloud, opening up access to your corporate SharePoint is nontrivial and not without risk. You may as well just pull it yourself and put it on the server manually.

Comment: It is updated about every month when we put out new versions of the app. We want to make it easy for non-programming employees to change the guide on the sharepoint, and also it would allow government contract users of the app to already have the credentials when logged in to use a route.

Comment: Sounds like the documentation versions in lockstep with the software. So the PDF ought to be part of your code base, in your source code repository, and deployed at the same time you deploy a new version of the software. This will allow you to maintain more than one environment (e.g. if you have a certification environment that is one version ahead) and also offers you a chance to QA the documentation as part of the release.  Pulling it directly bypasses the release process and introduces headache for your network engineers as well.